# Who scored the opening Star Wars fanfare for Disney+?

Tags: star-wars

At the beginning of *The Mandalorian* (and perhaps other *Star Wars* content, I don't know), an opening fanfare plays in the vein of what happens at the beginning of the MCU films. Over the fanfare are several images of *Star Wars* characters, such as C-3PO, a scout trooper, an x-wing pilot, and the Mandalorian. Who scored this fanfare? Could it be John Williams, Kevin Kiner, Michael Giachinno, or someone else entirely?

Answer (score 5):

With the release of *Kenobi*, we can see that this was specific to *The Mandalorian*, as *Kenobi* does not have that fanfare. While the score for *The Mandalorian* was written by Ludwig Göransson, the score for *Obi-Wan Kenobi* was written by John Williams and does not contain such an opening fanfare. Thus, it is apparent that this is not an MCU-style opening fanfare for all Disney+ Star Wars content. The intro style remains the same, but the music changes.
Edit: With the release of *Andor*, it appears that this intro fanfare is becoming an MCU-style fanfare intro for Star Wars content and that *Obi-Wan Kenobi* was simply an exception.

Answer (score -4):

[The Music](https://music.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiNVoBckLqLmxIiDi7Znavh_iEa0gBEuB) to *The Mandalorian* is scored by Swedish composer **Ludwig Göransson**.

Link to [Warm or Cold](https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=R595_ip-X-Y&feature=share) song.

Comment: until a new series begins, we can't know for sure if this is part of the Mandalorian series or similar to the MCU Marvel opening tag sequence. Since the score for every episode of the Mandalorian is available on streaming, and this opening is not part of the releases, I think this answer is incorrect for the question as asked